# BigQuery Scheduled Query - No Rows Updating?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, analytics

I have scheduled a query to go off every hour by calling a stored function. I basically take key Google Analytics metrics for the hour and insert them into a separate table that aggregates that data and can be pulled for reports.

Here's the function:

```
"BEGIN
  -- Define variables to construct the dynamic table name
  DECLARE tblName STRING;
  SET tblName = CONCAT('`myga-project.mytable.events_intraday_', FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE('America/New_York')), '`');

  -- Dynamic query execution
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
    INSERT INTO newdataset.newtable
    (event_date, event_hour, medium, total_sessions, total_conversions, total_purchase_revenue)
    SELECT
      event_date,
      event_hour,
      medium,
      SUM(sessions) AS total_sessions,
      SUM(conversions) AS total_conversions,
      SUM(purchase_revenue) AS total_purchase_revenue
    FROM (
      SELECT
        DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) AS event_date,
        EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') AS event_hour,
        traffic_source.medium AS medium,
        COUNT(user_id) AS sessions,
        SUM(CASE WHEN event_name = 'purchase' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS conversions,
        SUM(CASE WHEN event_name = 'purchase' THEN ecommerce.purchase_revenue_in_usd ELSE 0 END) AS purchase_revenue
      FROM %s
      WHERE DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) = CURRENT_DATE('America/New_York')
        AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
      GROUP BY event_date, event_hour, medium
    )
    GROUP BY event_date, event_hour, medium
    ORDER BY event_date, event_hour, medium;
  """, tblName);
END"
```

Returns: Executed.
Results: 0 rows added.

The query works but fails to insert the formatted rows. I've tried a few variations but still encountering problems.

I made a function since it won't let me schedule scripts. Storing the function was the best way to do this. This stored function is still not inserting rows which should be event date, medium, etc.

Comment: that looks like a "stored procedure" rather than a function (functions usually return something, they don't typically insert rows into tables). Do those generated table names actually exist? or Are you tryingto place the new data into that generated tablename?

Comment: One other way to debug if the rows are added is by querying the information_schema. for example: this query gives you the dml stats for that table                                                                                                                    `SELECT dml_statistics, start_time, end_time
FROM `silicon-comfort-329203`.`region-australia southeast1`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE statement_type = 'INSERT' order by start_time desc`

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell those generated tables do actually exist. Each day a new table is created with the Google Analytics data for that day. That table is then automatically purged at the end of the day. The goal is to extract a few data points and insert it into a new table and dataset that is never purged. The new table has also already been created and has a schema created based on those data points, So, not trying to insert that data into the generated table. I'm trying to pull the data from the generated table name, then insert it into another table. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Adrian-Maxwell those generated tables do actually exist. Each day a new table is created with the Google Analytics data for that day. That table is then automatically purged at the end of the day. The goal is to extract a few data points and insert it into a new table and dataset that is never purged. The new table has also already been created and has a schema created based on those data points, So, not trying to insert that data into the generated table. I'm trying to pull the data from the generated table name, then insert it into another table. Thanks so much!

Comment: Try running the select portion of your function as a query, does it return rows? Perhaps the where clause needs checking - could it be too precise? too limiting?